# just last column in Grid layout gets stretch

Tags: android, grid-layout

[image]

I want to stretch all columns in my grid layout equally , How can I do that ?

I am using this params for every cell

```
LayoutParams param2 =new LayoutParams(); 
       param2.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        param2.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;            
        param2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);          
        param2.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(i,FILL);
        param2.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(rowCount,FILL);
        param2.setGravity(Gravity.FILL);
```

Comment: post your xml layout

Answer (score 1):

Build Your Own GridLayout using nested LinearLayouts so you can customize it like you want, Or simply set the weight for each cell you add but you will need set you minimum sdk to 21

Comment: No I don't want to build it from zero

Answer (score 1):

Setting width of child dynamically

```
    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
 params.width = (parent.getWidth()/parent.getColumnCount()) -params.rightMargin - params.leftMargin;
 child.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: but we are adding columns dynamically

Comment: This will not help? You have to pass the values in the above code